# The difference link between "/usr/bin/npm" and " /usr/local/bin/npm"

Tags: shell, centos7

Today, In Centos7, I uninstall `nodejs` and `npm` and then install by [Linux Binaries (x64)](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz).

After unzip it ,then move it to `/usr/local/nodejs`. To make it global, I config soft link as follows:

```
#ln -s /usr/local/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/
#ln -s /usr/local/nodejs/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
```

What make me confused is that:

```
#nodejs -v
```

OK. However, but, the followin command:

```
#npm -v
```

Brings an error that the command cannot found.

Trying some approaches:

**After**

```
#ln -s /usr/local/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/
#npm -v
```

This command runs OK. What's make that different?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `/usr/bin` is in your PATH (as it should be) and `/usr/local/bin` is not.

Comment: What does `which nodejs` tell you?

Comment: I don't check it. But after reinstall it. nodejs -v, it show me its newest version.

Comment: Running `nodejs -v` does not tell you which `nodejs` is being executed, merely the version of whichever executable the shell is invoking.  Try `which nodejs` and `type nodejs` to figure out which executable and/or function is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bash, you have a file in your home called `.bash_profile`. This command runs a set of commands to configure your bash environment.

Also, all the `.sh` files inside `/etc/profile.d` are executed on every session that you execute.

So, inside those scripts, we have an environment variable called `PATH`, that are set on bash start.

If you try to do `echo $PATH`, you'll see a set of directories separated by colon `:`.

Every time that you try to run a command, the bash will check inside all directories setted inside this `$PATH` variable.

If your call are not found, we can get two hypotesis:

1. Your file or link is on a path that are not contained in `$PATH` dir.
2. Your file are not executable (need to do `chmod`).

So, check your `$PATH` to see if your command is linked on the right place, if you have a valid file and, lastly, if the execution permissions are valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why nodejs -v ok, npm -v wrong ? and They all link to /usr/local/bin path ?!

Comment: Try to check if your link is pointing to a valid file running ls `/usr/local/bin/npm`. Check if the symlink are pointing to a file that exists. And, also, check if you can run your `npm` command from your `/usr/loca/nodejs/bin/npm`.

Comment: Ok. I cannot connect office server now, I will try it later. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried again. Link to /usr/local/bin/npm is ok also. Thanks for your explaination also.